# How to properly use factories having multiple associations to the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, factory-bot

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, FactoryGirl 3.1.0 and FactoryGirlRails 3.1.0. I have a model that has two association to another model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to a_users, :class_name  => 'User'
  belongs_to b_users, :class_name  => 'User'
end
```

In my factory file I have:

```
factory :article, :class => Article do
  title "Sample title"

  association :a_users, factory: :user
  association :b_users, factory: :user
end
```

By using the above code it will create *two* users, but *I would like that both associations have the same user* (without to create multiple users). How can I make that?

Comment: what happens if you pass an array? association [:a_users,:b_users], factory: :user

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this isn't the most elegant solution or the one you were looking for, but what I would do is in your tests, use your factories to create an article and a user, then stub both `a_user` and `b_user` with the user you created.